# SDL, missing jpeg resync symbol

Tags: c, macos, compilation, linker, sdl

I'm trying to compile [this git repo](https://github.com/arnsa/Chip-8-Emulator) on my OSX. The only non-standard library it requires is SDL.

I've installed SDL with `brew install sdl` and compiled without errors with `gcc -o chip8 chip8.c -lSDL -L /usr/local/lib`.

On execution I get the following:

```
users-MBP:Chip-8-Emulator user$ ./chip8
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

I appear to have everything in place though:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib
...
libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
libSDL.a
libSDL.dylib 
libSDLmain.a
libjpeg.a 
libjpeg.dylib
libjpeg.8.dylib
...
```

**EDIT**

While the error in the suggested duplicate is identical, the origin of the problem is likely different and the accepted answer on that post provides no help in my case.

Comment: maybe symlink libJPEG.dylib to the actual library libjpeg.dylib ? (Notice the case difference)

Comment: @t0mm13b: it doesn't appear that he uses libjpeg though... hmm i guess he does? that doesn't have anything to do with SDL though.

Comment: @t0mm13b I tried that unfortunately I can't, `OSX` considers it a duplicate (it appears to ignore casing for referencing).

Comment: @Juicy: is there anything that indicates this is a problem with SDL? You could try compiling a tiny test programthat calls SDL_init and see if it works.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Same error message but different source of problem. As shown by the steps I've outlined in my question, I've already followed the recommendations of the accepted answer on that post.